# Metal Shading Language sinpi(x) always produces 0 on Intel HD Graphics 615?

Tags: macos, metal, vertex-shader

I'm working with a shader in MSL that uses `sinpi()` and `cospi()`. When I run the shader on a AMD Radeon R9 card, the results are as expected, but when I run the same shader on a Intel HD Graphics 615 the result of these two functions seems to be always 0.

When I replace them with `sin()` and `cos()` and do the multiplication with π myself, the results are correct again.

Could this be a bug in the Intel hardware?

Comment: It's not really an answer or a solution, but as another possible workaround, you could try `precise::sinpi()` and `precise::cospi()`.

Comment: Just tried, these versions also return 0 on this graphics card.